# HDFS into Cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

is it possible to migrate/replicate/copy/move processed files (using PIG) from local HDFS (lets say 192.168.0.10) to a cassandra (192.168.0.20)?

What I have in mind is that I literally create a java application to parse the file and re-insert them into cassandra.

Is there any other way in doing so?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Writing a Java program to migrate Hadoop data to Cassandra tables is actually a overkill. It would become more worse if you happen to perform the same periodically.

Instead , we can utilize a very useful feature of Hive which helps us to integrate Hive tables with external data sources. Its **Storage Handler Api** of hive, which integrates with external data sources like Cassandra/Oracle/Mysql etc.

There is already an `Hive-Cassandra Storage Handler API` implementation available , which we can very well reuse, kindly find the same in below url.

https://github.com/tuplejump/cash/tree/master/cassandra-handler

The idea is to create Hive external table which is configured with storage handler specs about the remote Cassandra host/table details.

Any write/read performed to this external table , will be handled by Hive through mapreduce jobs which talks with the Cassandra.

I hope this is the ideal way to integrate  Hive and Cassandra which takes very less efforts from us and very efficient too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing! it's definitely better than writing java program! I think i'd settle with Pig cassandra extension, because mostly the files in HDFS came from pig.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to move the data from Hadoop to Cassandra.

1. Using Java HDFS API and Cassandra API (inefficient).
2. Using Java MapReduce program (Parallel loading).
3. Using Pig (Parallel loading).
4. Using Hive (Parallel loading).
5. Using Spark (Parallel loading).

Out of all Pig is easier way to load the data from HDFS to Cassandra.
Pig has a storage type called CassandraStorage. It allows us to load the data into Cassandra in parallel.

Please see this link for more information:
https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport#Pig

Comment: thanks naga! I am still now trying to do it with pig while having this ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.].

Comment: Welcome @kenlz, You have to add this CassandraStorage jar into pig classpath. Can you check CassandraStorage is available in piggybank or not?

Comment: I fixed it by registering the jar to pig, but now I'm having this error ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlNativeStorage

It seems endless